# Confusing response of Create-Channel-Graph-API for Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I tried to create a new channel in a existed teams, and I got 400 Bad Request. 
Here is the request body and response:

request body:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.channel",
  "membershipType": "standard",
  "displayName": "channel-20230505",
  "members":
     [
        {
           "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
           "user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('3aa4fc7d-c1b0-4f85-a72c-ca5c9057ef3d')",
           "roles":["owner"]
        }
     ]
}
```

response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Channel thread creation failed for team thread id 19:aq62-ZP0OwlhsFWKOKJTm876BbkW3GXJE5TQufSUJNs1@thread.tacv2Failed to execute Skype backend request CreateThreadS2SRequest.",
        "innerError": {
            "message": "Channel thread creation failed for team thread id 19:aq62-ZP0OwlhsFWKOKJTm876BbkW3GXJE5TQufSUJNs1@thread.tacv2Failed to execute Skype backend request CreateThreadS2SRequest.",
            "code": "BadRequest",
            "innerError": {},
            "date": "2023-05-05T08:59:20",
            "request-id": "cd0853b6-7b3f-48f1-8460-ad6b51f5f715",
            "client-request-id": "cd0853b6-7b3f-48f1-8460-ad6b51f5f715"
        }
    }
}
```

I still knew nothing about how it occurred according to the API response messages.

Then, I tried to create channel with UI approach, and it told me "This team already has the max number of channels."
With the UI message mentioned above, I finally knew the root cause of this problem. Since there are lots of deleted channel in the team, it touch the channel number limit.

So my question is,

1. Does the message "Channel thread creation failed for team thread id {channel-id} Failed to execute Skype backend request CreateThreadS2SRequest." can be implied as channel number exceeded?
2. Can I got precise error response from this or any other graph APIs to figure out the root cause quickly?

I would be appreciate if someone can help me about it, thank you.

Comment: If the channel number is exceeded, ideally it shouldn't throw the error message you are getting. Could you please provide your query header along with the tenant details?

Comment: request be like:
"curl --location 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/91dbcfbc-bc25-4c0e-b970-925db575b468/channels' \
--header 'Content-type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {token}' \
--data-raw '{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.channel",
  "membershipType": "standard",
  "displayName": "channel-20230508",
  "members":
     ...
}'"
other information: 
{tenant id: "dcb0e1d1-6cde-4420-a658-ede52a8bead1", 
application id: "d0cca4c3-1446-45ce-aafe-80cf8e291bb7"}

Comment: Could you please share the team id which you are giving in request?

Comment: team id: 91dbcfbc-bc25-4c0e-b970-925db575b468
Thanks!

Comment: We also tested this and able to repro this issue and at our end also we are getting same error message when max channel limit has reached.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLwEt.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBdVI.png

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same. We will let you know once we get any updates on it.

Answer (score 0):

We got an update from engineering team saying that for standard channels, members are inherited from the team. To create a standard channel, pass the channel information without the member object.

To add members to a standard channel, use the Add member to team api
"[Add member to team - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)".